# Python: Finite sum with variable range "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, numpy

Aim: plot V vs. MF

[image: equation]

```
import numpy as np

V = np.arange(3,46, step = 6)
A = 3

# 'n' is a sequence of odd numbers (i.e. 1,3,5,7, ...)
n = V/A

mm = (n+1)/2
MF = sum((np.power(-1, m)) * np.exp(m * m * (V/n)) for m in range(1,mm))
```

I want m to form a sequence of `1, 2, 3, ... (n+1)/2`.

The problem I'm having is with the final line `range(1,mm)` which returns

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Seems to me the problem is that `m` cannot be variable for different numbers in the same sequence. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should ask a proper question but anyway what's the point of `range(1,mm)` with `mm` being an np.array?

Comment: @Eypros Basically, I don't know what I am doing. I tried explain better what I am trying to do below answer's comment (@SeljukGulcan)

Comment: essentially I need the `range` to vary with `n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import numpy as np`

`V = np.arange(3,46, step = 6)`

`A = 3`

'n' is a sequence of odd numbers (i.e. 1,3,5,7, ...)

`n = V/A`

'm' is the upper limit of summation; indices of summation are every integer between 1 to m.

`m = (n+1)/2`

'y' represents the element to be summed

`y = np.power(-1, m) * np.exp((m**2)*A)`

`MF = np.add.accumulate(y)`

`print(n)`

`print(MF)`

Answer (score 0):

`mm` variable is a numpy array containing the sequence of `1, 2, 3 ...` so `range(1, mm)` part doesn't make sense since `range` expects its arguments to be integers. If you want to iterate on `mm`, you can just

`MF = sum((np.power(-1, m)) * np.exp(m * m * (V/n)) for m in mm)`

**Note :** This is probably not what you want because `V` is a np.array, it makes resulting expression an array.

Since you are using numpy, you do not need to iterate on `mm` yourself. You can use `mm` directly:

```
MF = np.sum((-1) ** mm * np.exp(mm ** 2 * A))
>>> 2.4240441494100796e+83
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! `MF` in your note but it seem to return an array of values that are identical regardless of what `n` is. I was hoping that for `V = [ 3  9  15  21  27 ]` , `n = [ 1  3  5  7  9 ]` and  `m = [  1  2  3  4  5  ]`, the express for MF would give `MF = [ -20.085  1.63e+5  -5.32e+11  7.02e+20  -3.73e+32 ]`. Each datum in the `MF` array is different as it contains a different number of summations depending on what 'n' is according the eq. e.g. for `n = 3` the summation will contain 2 terms and for `n=4` the summation will contain 3 terms.